# Android - Kotlin - JUnit 5: How to test private methods?

Tags: android, kotlin, intellij-idea, junit5

General software organization question:
I have a Kotlin class file (under src/) with some 10 methods, only 1 of which should be visible outside the class (the rest should be private).
I also have a dozen JUnit test methods for testing the abovementioned methods, and I put all those in a different class file (under src/test/).
But the test methods cannot see the methods they're supposed to test, so I had to remove the private modifiers from the source code :(
What's a man to do?
JUnit 5, Kotlin for Android, on IntelliJ, if that matters.
Thank you

Answer (score 3):

> What's a man to do?

Check this [question and answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/100959/how-do-you-unit-test-private-methods).

Either a) test the private details *indirectly* by testing the public interface (which goes through the private methods) or b) Use `@VisibleForTesting` annotation to make a private function public for testing but clearly flagged as something that should not be used otherwise.

Comment: The annotation works like a charm, thank you!